# Choosing container for Azure Function EventHubb Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

By default the Azure Function of type Eventhub Trigger stores the offsets in a container inside a Storage Account named `azure-webjobs-eventhub`. Is there any possibility to specify another container? maybe playing with the AzureWebJobsStorage property?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Choosing container for Azure Function EventHubb Trigger

As Event trigger extension by default creates a checkpoint you cannot create change the container

[image]

For further information you can check [Event Trigger](https://medium.com/codex/azure-function-eventhub-trigger-checkpoint-12d5c2e48778)